# Como sincronizar dados entre diferentes usuarios?

Tags: android, xamarin

Eu sou novo na programação e estou tentando criar um aplicativo. Eu estou tentando descobrir como eu posso sincronizar os dados entre um grupo de usuários. Por exemplo, eu quero um aplicativo onde um usuário possa adicionar outro a um "grupo" e então eles possam gerenciar as mesmas informações. Se alguém alterar um campo no aplicativo, a informação teria que ser atualizada nos outros dispositivos do grupo também.

Obs: Cada um deles tendo seu próprio usuário.

Comment: Cara, aqui é em Português. Assim que traduzir eu te ajudo.

Comment: Valeu cara, ja traduzi.

Comment: Dê uma olhada aqui http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/br/library/os-couchdb/ e pesquise sobre MongoDB (Cloud) + SQLite (Local).